# Why is my program only looping through the File Not Found Exception?

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt a file by going one letter up for encryption and down a letter when decrypting. However, every time I run the program it just prompt me that "File Not Found" no matter what file I give as an input. What am I doing wrong? Any help or suggestions would be great. Below is my code:-

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Mission09
{
public static void main (String[]args)
{
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
File f;
Scanner fileIn;
PrintWriter fileOut;
PrintWriter fileOutDecrypt;

String fileName = "";
String userAnswer = "";
String line = "";

  try
{
  //Get file name from the user
  System.out.println ("Please enter the name of the file.");
  fileName = in.nextLine ();

  //Get user input for encryption or decryption
  System.out.println ("Would you like to encrypt or decyrpt the file?");
  userAnswer = in.nextLine ();

  //Build the File and attach a Scanner to it
  f = new File (fileName);
  fileIn = new Scanner (f);

  //Loop through the file
  if (userAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase ("Encrypt"))
{
  fileOut = new PrintWriter ("Encrypted.txt");

  while (fileIn.hasNextLine ())
    {
      line = fileIn.nextLine ();

   for (int i = 0; i < line.length (); i++)
    {
      Character c = ' ';
      char ch = line.charAt (i);

      if (c.isLetter (ch))
        {
          if (ch == 'z')
              ch = 'a';

          else
              ch++;
        }

      fileOut.print(ch + " ");
    }

    }

}

  if (userAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase ("Decrypt"))
{
  fileOut = new PrintWriter ("Decrypted.txt");

  while (fileIn.hasNextLine())
    {
      line = fileIn.nextLine();

      for (int i = 0; i < line.length (); i--)
    {
      Character x = ' ';
      char cha = line.charAt (i);

      if (x.isLetter (cha))
        {
          if (cha == 'z')
              cha = 'a';

          else
              cha--;

       fileOut.print(cha + " ");
        }

      fileOut.close();
    }
    }

}

}

catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
     System.out.println("Sorry that file cannot be found. Please enter another file.");
}

}

}
```

Comment: did you try providing the whole path of the file to `fileName` ?

Comment: I pasted full path and it didn't tell file not found. i.e (C:\Users\your_users\Documents\test.txt)

Comment: Can you please add the statement `e.printStackTrace();` into your catch block, and [edit] in the output? The exception isn't only thrown if the file doesn't exist; it can also be thrown if the program doesn't have permission to access the file, or the file is locked by another program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input the whole path of the file. It worked for me.
ex: `C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxx\Desktop\test.txt`.

Also include `fileOut.close()` at the end of the `if` condition for encryption

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the absolute path and the complete filename with the proper extension.
Surely the problem is in the way you are giving the path to the file.

I tried with the absolute path and the same code works fine for me.

example from my playpen: `C:\code\WprkSpacePlaypen\Temp\src\abhijeet.txt`